# Understanding json dump in python 3.5

Tags: python, json, api

I am not well versed in json or python. I'm creating a simple script to grab local current temperature and place it in a txt file (as I'm assuming I can get python to read the txt file at a later step). So far I've managed to create the txt file with the json data but I would only like to write to the txt file the relevant data I want.

```
import requests
import json
key = [KEY]
while 1:
    res = requests.get('http://api.wunderground.com/api/' + key + '/geolookup/conditions/q/[STATE]/[ZIP].json')
json_string = res.json()
with open("weather_result.txt","w") as fp:
    json.dumps(json_string, fp)
temperature_string = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f']
print (temperature_string)
```

Where am I going wrong? I can't seem to understand strings or dicts with this json dump.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I can't understand your code. `while 1`? Where is `parsed_json` defined?

Comment: Are you familiar with `fp.write('string here')`?

Comment: You haven't told us what went wrong or what you want in the file. It looks like you have an infinite loop just doing the request over and over. Should the text file be a json dump of just the stuff in `parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f']`. You call it `temperture_string`... is it just a string? Do you really want to write a json serialization of the string or just the string? Do want to write this data muliple times (then terminate with a newline so you can tell them apart)?

Comment: After reading these comments I realized my mistake, "parsed_json" was not defined as I meant to use "json_string" instead. Both that and "while 1:" are remnants of old code I didn't realize were still there. All I wanted to do was grab the current temperature. I started with using json because I was following a tutorial and moved on from that.

Answer (score 1):

I have identified 2 problems in your code.

1. In order to save to save your result to a file. Change `json.dumps` to `json.dump`.

Example: 

`with open("weather_result.txt","w") as fp:
    json.dump(json_string, fp)`

2. Variable `parsed_json` is never defined. Maybe you should assign `parsed_json` to `res` in your code.

Comment: Typo in my example. Meant json.dump, not json.dumps

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have one statement in the loop, your code will just keep requesting that page as fast as it can in a tight loop. You need to move the remaining code inside the loop. Then, since all you want is the temperature, skip writing the json and just write that part. Put a sleep in there to be nice to the weather underground and you should be good to go.

Notice that since this code sleeps and reopens the file every time it wants to use it. You could just keep the file open by moving the `with` outside of the `while` (and potentially add a `fp.flush()` after the write so that others can read current data). Its a trade-off though. This way, you could move or delete the file in another shell and this program would just start filling a new one.

```
import requests
import time

key = [KEY]
while 1:
    res = requests.get('http://api.wunderground.com/api/' + key + '/geolookup/conditions/q/[STATE]/[ZIP].json')
    with open("weather_result.txt","a") as fp:
        temperature_string = res.json()['current_observation']['temp_f']
        print(temperature_string)
        fp.write('{}\n', temperature_string)
    time.sleep(5*60)
```